# pngcrush command line do nothing for -text option

Tags: macos, terminal, png, pngcrush

From this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush I use this command line in Mac OS X Terminal

```
pngcrush -rem text InputFile.png OutputFile.png
```

It's work ! But this :

```
pngcrush -text b "Software" "pngcrush" image1.png image2.png
```

do nothing and output like launching pngcrush without option.

What's wrong ?

Comment: What is your expected `image2.png` result, and what is the actual result? Can you provide the image?

Comment: Here is my png http://i.imgur.com/3Y7KaEo.png I try to change ImageReady to pngcrush (you can open it with text editor to view the key or use pngtweak on windows).

Comment: It seems that text insertion in pngcrush is buggy. I'd try ImageMagick or this: https://github.com/gbenison/png-text-embed

Comment: Thank you ! But can't 'Make' png-text-embed (Mac OS 10.6.8 ?).

Answer (score 0):

The current version of pngcrush (version 1.7.67) should do what you want. Some bugs with text insertion were fixed in pngcrush-1.7.29 and 1.7.67.